# Serial Programming - Termios. Getting stuck when reading 0x00 byte from device

Tags: c, unix, serial-port, posix, termios

I'm using [termios](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/termios#Reading_and_Setting_Parameters) API to read from / write to a device configured in the serial interface. The code I'm using is the following:

```
// Open serial interface
const char *device = "/dev/ttyS0";
int fd = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
if (fd == -1)
  printf( "failed to open port\n" );

fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

// Get current configuration of serial interface
struct termios config;
tcgetattr(fd, &config);

// Set configuration of device
...
...
//

// Apply configuration to descriptor
tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &config);

// Send order to device
unsigned char order[2];
int res;
unsigned char m = 0x00;
unsigned char s = 0x00;

order[0] = 0xc1; // Byte 193
order[1] = m;

res = write(fd, &order[0], 2);
if (res != 2)
  return -1;

res = read(fd, &s, 1);
if ((res != 1) || (res == -1))
  return -1;
```

The serial port opens correctly and the device is also correctly configured. If I print the configuration (`config`) in gdb I get the following:

> {c_iflag = 8240, c_oflag = 0, c_cflag = 3251, c_lflag = 0, c_cc =
>   "\003\034\177\025\004\000\000\000\021\023\032\000\000\000\000\026\001\000\000\000\033[\000\000\000\000\000\000DCAB@P\000\000HY\000",
>   reserved = {0, 0, 1552337580}, c_ispeed = 9600, c_ospeed = 9600}

Then I can use the write function to send orders to the device but I cannot use the read function. The code gets stuck after running the line `res = read(fd, &s, 1);` and I get no response (see below). Any hint?

[image]

**EDIT:**

The `// Set configuration of device` block is as follows:

```
cfsetispeed(&config, B9600);
cfsetospeed(&config, B9600);

config.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
config.c_cflag |= CS8;    

config.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
config.c_cflag |= 0;

config.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
config.c_cflag &= ~PARODD;
config.c_cflag |= (0 | 0);

config.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
config.c_iflag |= (INPCK | ISTRIP);

config.c_oflag = 0;
config.c_lflag = 0;

config.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
config.c_cc[VTIME]=0;
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that there's something to read from the serial port? If you make the descriptor non-blocking, does `read` return with `-1` and `errno` set to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`?

Comment: Where does the "0x00 byte" come in, and what is its significance?  If it's supposed to be a string terminator, for example, then I can imagine several variations on *sender-side* flaws that would end transmission with the last byte before the terminator.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the device is connected to the serial port. I don't know if `read` returns with `-1` since the code gets stuck. @John Bollinger the 0x00 byte is supposed to be the default value of the device being inactive.

Comment: The reason your "code gets stuck" is because there's nothing to read. Since the descriptor is *blocking* that means `read` will block (i.e. not return and seem to be stuck) forever until there's actually anything to read. If you set the `O_NONBLOCK` flag for the descriptor `fd` then the `read` call will return `-1` with `errno` set to one of the errors mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude then what's the solution for it? I've just tried removing `O_NONBLOCK` and the issue is still there

Comment: The problem is that there's no data being sent. Is the other side of the serial cable doing what it should be doing? And you should *set* the flag to be able to check.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The device is not doing what it's supposed to do. I have edited the question with the `Set configuration of device` block. There you can see the input and output flags.

Comment: *"... and the device is also correctly configured."* -- No, it is not. Your termios configuration is incomplete and improper.  The **read()** statement blocks because your serial terminal probably has flow control enabled.  Study  [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html) and [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237).

Comment: @sawdust the first guide is the one I used to set everything. I didn't enable any flow control, in fact, I tried every possible option before defining the setup, and the lines `config.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;` and `config.c_iflag |= (IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);` are commented.
Tried also by forcing `config.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);` and nothing happened either.

Answer (score 1):

Although `O_NONBLOCK` was added at the time of open, `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0)` was called below, equivalent to blocking mode.

```
fd = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);   // The O_NONBLOCK flag is overwritten
```

If there is no data on the serial port, it will be blocked.